# Dual Boot Ubuntu 12.04/Windows8 grub

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-8

I installed Ubuntu on 12.04 on my Samsung laptop alongside Windows 8.
To install Ubuntu I disabled the bios security and enables CSM OS.

The installation went fine and Ubuntu works great.
The problem is that when from the grub menu I select Windows 8 or Windows 8 recovery
it doesn't load anything.

If I in the bios I enable the Secure OS option than I don't get the grub menu,
but Windows 8 detect some error and after a while loads fine.
Disabling again the Secure OS option in the bios, I get the grub menu and Ubuntu works fine.

What can I do to fix this and normally dual boot either Ubuntu or Windows?

Thanks a lot in advance,
Luca

Comment: What is CSM OS?

Comment: have you tried - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: I'll try to use boot-repair and let you know, thanks!

Comment: Ok the boot-repair option seems to have fixed it.
There is only one thing I can't understand, now in the grub menu there are a lot of entry that I can't fully understand like:  some .efi and .bkp locations...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luca Cerone fixed the issue in a comment.

> Ok the boot-repair option seems to have fixed it. There is only one thing I can't understand, now in the grub menu there are a lot of entry that I can't fully understand like: some .efi and .bkp locations...

[Luca Cerone Jan 16](https://askubuntu.com/questions/243937/dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-windows8-grub#comment302349_243937)